# Google Play Console - The private key doesn't match the current app certificate

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I am trying to upload a bundle to I can do Closed Testing with app on my own devices. When I try to upload I am told that I need to opt-in to "Play App Signing":

[image]

When I try to upload a private key under **App integrity** I am being told "**The private key doesn't match the current app certificate**"

How do I fix this? I don't know where the "current app certificate" is or how I would generate/upload a new certificate.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could fix this problem was to rebuild the app with completely different package names. So I changed com.myapps.thisapp to com.myapps.thisapp2 and I was able to upload.

I guess whatever keys/certificates that were on my machine from 8 years ago were needed to upload a newer version of my app.